# ASP.NET 5 SignalR not working with .NET client

Tags: signalr, iis-express, asp.net-core

I work on a ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET vNext) website. I use SignalR server (1.0 Beta 3) for some processing. It it is correctly set up because I can successfully invoke server methods from a Javascript browser client.

But when a I use .NET client (.NET 4.5 with SignalR 2.2.0), the method invoke fail with the generic "error 500".

I have downloaded both SignalR server and client sources to be able to debug them. I have seen that `DefaultHttpClient.Post()` client method is called with valid "`postData`" parameter, but the server `PersistentConnectionMiddleware.Invoke()` method has a http context without any "`Form`" value inside the request. And it makes SignalR server side failing in the `ForeverTransport.ProcessSendRequest()` method.

The post form seems to be forgotten during the transfer between the client and the server (I use the default IIS Express server).

Any idea? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I saw the [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/91) you opened and have committed a fix/workaround.

At the moment it doesn't look like SignalR 3 works with the client due to the fact it expects all requests to be form encoded.  The [workaround](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/f713ec6ed7b3933e63903dda25102156a8da26dc/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server/Transports/ForeverTransport.cs#L131-L155) is to update `ProcessSendRequest()` so it can get the non-form-encoded data from the 2.2 .NET client;

```cs
protected virtual async Task ProcessSendRequest()
{
    var data = await GetData().PreserveCulture();

    if (Received != null)
    {
        await Received(data).PreserveCulture();
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetData()
{
    if (Context.Request.HasFormContentType)
    {
        var form = await Context.Request.ReadFormAsync().PreserveCulture();
        return form["data"];
    }
    else
    {
        var stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(Context.Request.Body);
        var output = await stream.ReadToEndAsync().PreserveCulture();
        var decoded = UrlDecoder.UrlDecode(output);
        return decoded.Replace("data=", "");
    }
}
```